# Is it really a bad practice to let « PermitRootLogin yes » on a production server?

Tags: ssh, root

One day (4 years ago), I rebooted my server. After the reboot was complete, I tried to login as usual with my regular (non-root) account. At that time, I had `PermitRootLogin no`.

I got the answer

> The system is going down on Sun Aug 16 00:43:48 2009

and couldn't login. But it was not true, the server was not going to shutdown. It had shut down, but it was already up. Actually, I noticed that for some mysterious reason, the `/etc/nologin` file, created by `shutdown` hadn't be deleted.

When the `/etc/nologin` file exists, SSH doesn't allow any user to login, except **root**.

Since `PermitRootLogin` was set to « no », I couldn't login and was forced to hard reboot my server in rescue mode, mount the file system, delete the `/etc/nologin` file, and reboot.

So, what do you think about letting `PermitRootLogin` set to « yes », but disable its password (`passwd -l root`), so that only SSH-key connection is allowed for root?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the actual value of disabling remote root login using ssh](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34915/what-is-the-actual-value-of-disabling-remote-root-login-using-ssh)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sshd already supports the scenario you want:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

This permits root to use any authentication method except password.

For a single-sysadmin scenario this is fine. Though, as has been discussed *ad nauseam* here and elsewhere, if you have multiple sysadmins, none of them should be logging in as root.

Answer (score 4):

In a system where you are the only administrator, that is fine.

But organizations with lots of systems and lots of administrators need functional auditing. This means shared credentials must be minimized, even if they are ssh  keys. Otherwise you would never be able to know who preformed what action.